# Unable to filter, order and search the data for nested endpoints API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

My API endpoint is http://127.0.0.1:7009/apps/2/versions

I am unable to filter, order and search the particular version data

models.py:

```
class App(models.Model):
    app_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,help_text="app_id of the app",unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,help_text="name of the app")

class AppVersion(models.Model):
     app_version = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     app_description = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
```

Views.py :

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter,SearchFilter
class AppVersionListView(mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.CreateModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = appVersionsSerializer
    queryset = AppVersion.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,SearchFilter,)
    filter_fields = ('id','app_version','app_description ')
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    search_fields =('app_version','app_description')
```

serializers.py : (class for app_versions)

```
class appVersionsSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = AppVersion
        fields = ('apps','app_version','app_description')
```

I want to filter the versions data based on "app_description" i.e.,

GET:
http://127.0.0.1:7009/apps/2/versions?app_description =FileCommander

Expected Output :

Should filter the data and return results which is having that description

```
[
{
        "apps": 2,
        "app_version": "v1",
        "app_description ":"FileCommander"
}]
```

Actual Output :

```
[
{
        "apps": 2,
        "app_version": "v1",
        "app_description ":"FileCommander"
},
{
        "apps": 2,
        "app_version": "v2",
        "app_description ":"cooking"
}]
```

How can I search , filter or order the versions data?

Comment: Can you provide your serializer class

Comment: It looks like you have a trailing space in your `app_description ` parameter ; seems strange.

Comment: @ frankie567 no, that space is added while i am pasting here

Comment: I have included serializer class for app_versions

Comment: According to the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), the property name to define the fields to filter on is `filterset_fields` (not `filter_fields`).

Comment: I tried with that also but still its not working

Comment: filter_fields is working for other api's but when to comes to this nested API "djangofilterbackend" itself  is not getting called

Comment: Which versions of `django`, `django-rest-framework` and `django-filter` are you using?

Comment: django-rest-framework = 3.9.1

django = 2.2a1

django-filter = 2.1.0